# How to use javascript to remove focus/hover state on click in mobile

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, hover, tooltip

I have a tooltip that appears on hover. The problem is that in order to remove focus/hover state in mobile, you have to click outside of the .explanation div. I want to mak it so that you can also close it my

```
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <h5>h5 text</h5>
      <div class="explanation">
        <div>
          <p>An explanatory paragraph <a>x</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css looks like this:

```
.main {
  .explanation {
    &::before {
      content: "[hover to show]";
    }

    p {
      background: #edf6ff;
      display: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 12px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      
      a {
        
          content: '[close]';
          outline: 5px solid blue;
          position: absolute;
          top: -5px;
          right: -20px;
        }
    }

    &:hover p {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pgreenconsumertrack/7c06dtLq/51/)

This works perfectly on desktop, but ON MOBILE I want to be able to remove the focus on the element by clicking on the [x] a tag. You can already close it by clicking anywhere else, but I want to be able to click the X (which is inside) to close as well.

I figure it will be something like:

```
const closeButton = document.querySelector(
    '.main .explanation p a'
);

const main = document.querySelector('.main');

closeButton.addEventListener('click', removeFocus, false);

function removeFocus(event) {
    main.blur();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

But this doesn't do anything, at least not in Chrome. How can I toggle off the hover state on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `css` hover use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.
On `mouseenter` or `touchstart` add `active` class and on `mouseleave` remove it.
When we click on close button remove the class

```js
const closeButton = document.querySelector('.main .explanation p a');
const explanation = document.querySelector('.main .explanation');
const addActiveClass = (e) => {
    explanation.classList.add('active');
}
const removeActiveClass = (e) => {
    explanation.classList.remove('active');
}

closeButton.addEventListener('click', toggleExplanation, false);
explanation.addEventListener('mouseenter', addActiveClass);
explanation.addEventListener('mouseleave', removeActiveClass);
explanation.addEventListener('touchstart', addActiveClass);

function toggleExplanation(event) {
  explanation.classList.toggle('active');
  event.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // Check if the clicked element is outside the target element
  if (!explanation.contains(e.target)) {
    removeActiveClass(e)
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  .explanation {
    &::before {
      content: "[hover to show]";
    }

    p {
      background: #edf6ff;
      display: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 12px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;

      a {
        content: '[close]';
        outline: 5px solid blue;
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        right: -20px;
      }
    }

    &.active p {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <h5>h5 text</h5>
      <div class="explanation">
        <div>
          <p>An explanatory paragraph <a>x</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to make some modification in css and js with extra class in html and your code will working fine

HTML

```
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <h5>h5 text</h5>
      <div class="explanation show-tooltip">
        <div>
          <p>An explanatory paragraph <a class="close-tooltip">x</a>
          </p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
  .explanation {
    &::before {
      content: "[___]";
    }

    p {
      background: #edf6ff;
      display: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 12px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;

      a {
        content: '[close]';
        outline: 5px solid blue;
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        right: -20px;
      }
    }

    
  }
  .explanation.show-tooltip {
    &:hover p {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Get all close-tooltip elements
  var closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.close-tooltip');

  // Add click event listeners to close-tooltip elements
  closeButtons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      // Prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag
      event.preventDefault();

      // Find the closest parent with class 'explanation' and remove 'show-tooltip' class
      var explanation = button.closest('.explanation');
      if (explanation) {
        explanation.classList.remove('show-tooltip');
        setTimeout(() => {
            explanation.classList.add('show-tooltip');
        }, 1000)
      }
    });
  });
});
```